# Constexpr non member function and reference Argos

Tags: c++, constexpr

If I have a non member constexpr function taking a reference parameter does it have to be constant reference

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

> If I have a non member constexpr function taking a reference parameter does it have to be constant reference?

No, it doesn't but it is better.

The primary purpose of a `constexpr` function is to evaluate expressions at compile time. It does not make sense to pass a non-`const` reference to such a function. If you choose to modify the input object in the function, I'll have to ask you why? If you don't modify the input object, it is better to use a `const` reference, just like it is always a good idea to make member functions that don't modify an object to be `const` member functions.

The following code does not work since a temporary object can't be used when the function expects a non-`const` reference

```
struct Foo { int i; };

constexpr bar(Foo& f) { return f.i * 2; }

int main()
{
   int arr[bar({20})]; // Can't use a temp object
}
```

The following code works. The function can be used with temporary objects as well as objects that can be used as lvalues.

```
struct Foo { int i; };

constexpr bar(Foo const& f) { return f.i * 2; }

int main()
{
   int arr[bar({20})];
   Foo f{20};
   int v = bar(f);
}
```

Comment: Any references or links

Comment: @BlairDavidson, I added a bit more description to explain my "better" qualification. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  No.

Long answer: No, because the `const` operator only ensures that the data of the non-member function will not be changed - however, if you pass a 
parameter, this foreign parameter **may be changed**